# Evaluating Python Code From the CAPI and getting Output

Tags: python, python-c-api

I'm trying to emulate `code.InteractiveInterpreter` from the embedded Python C API. I'm using `PyEval_Evalcode` to evaluate the user input. I am trying to evaluate user input in the interpreter and return the output as a string (just like the interpreter would). However, `PyEval_Evalcode` returns a multitude of datatypes wrapped in `PyObject*`.  Is there any way to do what I am trying to do?

Constraints: It needs to be done using the embedding api. Cannot be done using `PyRun_RunSimpleString()` and laying down a `code.InteractiveInterpreter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object returned by PyEval_Evalcode() can be transformed to a Python string using PyObject_Repr() or PyObject_Str().  The resultant python string can be turned into a regular C string with PyString_AsString().

Answer (score 0):

I have binary string and cannot return it as string because of null terminated string.

if(PyString_Check(pValue))
                {
                    const char* s=/*PyBytes_AsString*/PyString_AsString(PyObject_Repr(pValue)); //return hex representation in ascii
                    int sz=PyString_Size(pValue);//size is valid
                    const char* s= PyString_AsString(pValue);//return only  below null terminated string
                }